Binding a mesh object to a specific control point of a curves object
Is it somehow possible to bind a mesh to a specific control point from a curves object? On curves object it seems that i can´t set hooks unfortunately. I would appreciate any help!

By "a specific vertex", do you mean a "point" that is not a "control point" ?

Hey, i´m not sure what counts as a control point in a "curves" object but i just mean one specific point of all the different curves in this object.

On one hand, could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/, to illustrate what you mean by "curves" object ? At this time, I imagine that in the Spreadsheet Editor, you see one "curve" made of many "splines".  On the other hand, can we assume that a "specific vertex/point" is a vertex that you can select in Edit Mode ?

Unfortunately i can´t provide the file directly but i will try to explain it further: The object itself is a curves object and not a curve object. You get a curves object if you go to "Add -> Curves -> Fur" for example. So basically this type of object you use for all geometry node based hairs. If i select this object and go into edit mode, i can see all the control points and select one. Now i want to hook a mesh object to this specific control point.

Yes you can! Just select the point you wish then 'Ctrl+select' the mesh object (if you can't do it through viewport, do it through Outliner) and then 'Ctrl+P > Make Vertex Parent'. But why do you say you can't do hooks for curves? It's totally possible!!

Hey, many thanks for your answer! But it also doesn´t seem to work with a vertex parent unfortunately. It´s possible with a "curve" object but not with a "curves" object as far as i know. But it has to be a curves object in my case.
